# Get parent widget height in flutter

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

I want create `statefulWidget` and want in this widget get parent widget **height**. Don't want do this by sending **height** data from parent widget. How can I do this?

Comment: by using `LayoutBuilder`? the docs say: *"Builds a widget tree that can depend on the parent widget's size."*

Comment: How can I do with ``LayoutBuilder``?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html

Comment: but honestly you should use `FractionallySizedBox` - docs say: *"A widget that sizes its child to a fraction of the total available space.*" - that way you can do that with one `Widget` while using `LayoutBuilder` you need most likely two `Widget`s: `LayoutBuilder` and some `SizedBox` or `Container`

Answer (score 13):

Use **LayoutBuilder** as a child widget.

```
LayoutBuilder(builder: (ctx, constraints) {
      return 
          Container(
            height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.5,
            width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.5,
            child: Text('Inside Layout Builder'),
     );
  })
```

As per this code `Container` will use half of the height and width of parent widget.